# Are Theists and physicists talking about an empty universe or no universe at all?

Tags: metaphysics, theology, physics, nothing

When they talk about the beginning of the universe, are Theists and physicists talking about an empty universe or no universe at all?

> [It is fairly straightforward](https://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/Philosophy/axioms/axioms/node18.html) to imagine an empty Universe - an
>   infinite set of points represented by some set of abstract coordinates
>   with no ``objects'' located at any of the points. Hmmmm, isn't that
>   what mathematics is all about for the first umpty years one studies
>   it?
>
> Note well that (empty or not) we can imagine putting things at those
>   coordinates, using those coordinates to label the things and help to
>   sort them into sets (including disjoint ''identity sets''), just as we
>   can imagine putting things ``into'' the empty set (via the Union
>   operation) and creating a non-empty set.
>
> There is, however, a deeper notion of ''emptiness'', that of
>   ``non-being''. The notion of no box at all.

Comment: i always thought that physicists tell us that space **and** time were created at the Big Bang.  that there was **not** a vacuum sitting around and time ticking off before the Big Bang.  there **was** no *"before"* the BB.

Comment: well clearly no physical universe, but that needn't be equivalent i guess to its expression in logic ?? @robertbristow-johnson

Comment: well, even though i believe in God, i have absolutely no idea what God might have been doing *"before"* the BB was so willed.  i don't even know if God exists in space and time as we do.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson yeah, difficult. i always struggled with the logos stuff, esp

Comment: Well, the empty set doesn't have any points at all in it. Once you have a set of points, the universe is no longer empty. In math a coordinate space (say the 2-D plane for simplicity) has lots of points, namely all the ordered pairs (a,b) with a and b real numbers. So your mathematical analogy doesn't work. We could add some rules saying what it means for there to "be something at a location," but that's adding even more structure.

Comment: In the Hebrew bible there was chaos before God did the creating. It's also implied that there was water. As for the physicists, they don't deny that there may have been something before the big bang, but it's something that we currently haven't the faintest inkling how to find out, so it's not really a topic that physicists spend much time on.